# Showing different titles in table TR on certain rows with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have values in database which I show in table on page. **They are always 10**. I want to show different `Name` when the loop hit 9th and 10th rows. I've tried this which doesn't seems to be the correct way

```
while ($row=$result_rates->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$counter = 0;
    foreach ($row as $r){
      if($counter<9)
      {     
         echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$r['number'].'</td>                          
                <td>$ <span>'.$r['price'].'</span></td>
              </tr>';
       }
       else {

         echo '<tr>
                    <td>Number 9</td>                          
                    <td>$ <span>'.$r['price'].'</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Number 10</td>                         
                    <td>$ <span>'.$r['price'].'</span></td>
                </tr>'; 
       }
    }
}
```

Is this possible with tables and how?

Comment: You never actually increase the counter

Comment: Also  since you used `MYSQLI_ASSOC` so i don't think you need `foreach()`. it's really unclear what you are doing

Comment: also consider limiting the rowset within the query itself rather than within php, for efficiency when dealing with larger table sizes in future.

Comment: It's not about the limit of the results. It's all about just static/different row names on rows 9 and 10 because in database are number values `9` and `10` but I want to display `Number 9` and `Number 10`. The others are rended as `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
$counter = 1;
foreach ($row as $r){

    $html = ($counter==9 || $counter==10)?  '<tr><td>Number '.$counter.'</td><td>$ <span>'.$r['price'].'</span></td></tr>'  : '<tr><td>'.$r['number'].'</td><td>$ <span>'.$r['price'].'</span></td></tr>'
    echo $html;
    $counter++; //you forgot it
}
```

***Or you can try this:-***

```
$counter = 1;
foreach ($row as $r){

    $html = ($counter>8)?  '<tr><td>Number '.$counter.'</td><td>$ <span>'.$r['price'].'</span></td></tr>'  : '<tr><td>'.$r['number'].'</td><td>$ <span>'.$r['price'].'</span></td></tr>'
    echo $html;
    $counter++; //you forgot it
}
```

Note:- `while` is not needed because `$row` have all records in it already

Answer (score 1):

**1st :** Forgot to increment the variable `$counter++` .

**2nd :** No need while loop since it's fetching all the rows .

```
$row=$result_rates->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```

**3rd :** Simple concatenate like below .

```
<td>Number '.$counter.'</td>
```

**PHP :**

```
$counter = 1;
foreach ($row as $r){

      if($counter<=8)
      {     
         echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$r['number'].'</td>                          
                <td>$ <span>'.$r['price'].'</span></td>
              </tr>';
       }
       else {

         echo '<tr>
                    <td>Number '.$counter.'</td>                          
                    <td>$ <span>'.$r['price'].'</span></td>
                </tr>'; 
       }

        $counter++; //here incrementing the variable .

}
```

Comment: Thanks but what I receive is `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,Number 9`, it should be `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,Number 9,Number 10`. Why is that? I've tried to change the if - `if($counter<8)`